# Как отменить text-decoration line-through для дочернего элемента

Tags: html, css

Если есть верстка такого вида:

```
<span class="OldPrice">
  2799
  <span class="PriceCurrency">руб</span>
</span>
```

Возможно ли отменить действие перечеркивания для дочернего элемента? Я хочу что бы руб. не было перечеркнуто (В текущей верстке)

css:

```
.OldPrice{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.OldPrice span{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/zj890ktw/1/

```css
.OldPrice{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.OldPrice span{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="OldPrice">2799 <span class="PriceCurrency">rub</span></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line-through` не распространяется на блочные и плавающие элементы

```css
.OldPrice{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.OldPrice > span{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="OldPrice">2799<span class="PriceCurrency">&nbsp;rub</span></span>
```

Comment: Более лаконично, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.OldPrice {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.OldPrice .PriceCurrency {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.OldPrice .PriceCurrency:before {
  content: "\A0";
}
```

```html
<span class="OldPrice">2799<span class="PriceCurrency">rub</span></span>
```

Comment: Благодарен! Скоро отмечу как правильный